# FireQuery Firebug add-on breaking Foundation 5 reveal on OSX

Tags: firebug, zurb-foundation

Whilst trying to open a Foundation 5 (5.2.1) reveal via javascript (`$('#reveal-id').foundation('reveal', 'open')`) I've been getting these annoying errors:

`this.dispatchevent is not a function`

Depending on what I changed, sometimes it became:

`settings is undefined`

After a lot of cursing and ripping everything out (leaving me with [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blizzke/vL5Cd/)) I've found the problem and wanted to share the solution with you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**

If you have the FireQuery extension (1.4.1) for Firebug installed, that might be the culprit.

**Long answer**

While using that jsFiddle it turned out to be working in both Chrome and FF. After copying the code and using it [as plain HTML](https://gist.github.com/Blizzke/9703686), it still worked in Chrome but failed in FF. But it was exactly the same code! At that point I started disabling FF add-ons. The journey ended when I arrived at FireQuery.
Hopefully I can save some of you from a very frustrating day with this. Why it's actually still working in jsFiddle with the add-on enabled eludes me at this point. I also don't know if it is limited to OSX only, could be on Windows as well.

Comment: Did you also let the [FireQuery author](http://discuss.binaryage.com/) know about this?

Comment: Sure did, hope they can fix it asap because I already miss it :/

Comment: Unfortunately the author has replied that it won't be fixed anytime soon. http://discuss.binaryage.com/t/firequery-on-osx-breaks-zurb-foundation5-reveal/1599

Answer (score 1):

Note that the functionality of including an external script is already implemented in Firebug via the [`include()`](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Include) command. jQuery is already available as alias by default, so just call

```js
include("jquery")
```

and you're good to go.

For the part of inspecting jQuery data attached to the HTML elements you can use the (commercial) [Illuminations for Developers](http://www.illuminations-for-developers.com/). Though it doesn't display the data inline inside the [*HTML* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel), which makes it hard to use.

Comment: The FireQuery shows the internal jQuery data in the HTML Firebug page. I use it all the time to see if components initialised correctly and so on. I think you might have misunderstood its functionality

Comment: Well, it at least covers the part of injecting jQuery into a page. It obviously doesn't include all the features of FireQuery, but there's another extension that does it. So I updated my answer.

Comment: It's also a really nice plugin it seems, thank you for that. I'll test it shortly and see if it works in my situation.

Comment: Yeah euh, nvmd... Not going to pay for something like that.